# Export whole silverlight control to image

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, export, imaging

I'm trying to save silverlight control to an image, but getting troubles when control has scrollviewer inside.

[image]

So i'm getting the exact picture i see on the screen (cropped and with scrollbar).
How to get correct result which should look like on the picture below?

[image]

Here is the xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="save" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <Border Background="Gray" Width="100" Height="100" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And button handler:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScaleTransform scaleTrans = new ScaleTransform();
        double scale = 1;
        scaleTrans.CenterX = 0;
        scaleTrans.CenterY = 0;
        scaleTrans.ScaleX = scale;
        scaleTrans.ScaleY = scale;
        var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(LayoutRoot, scaleTrans);
        var i = Telerik.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap);
        var dialog = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Png (*.png)|*.png",
            DefaultExt = "png",
        };

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (Stream stream = dialog.OpenFile())
            {
                var encoder = new Telerik.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(i);
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you put your code where you are showing the image in some container over here

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. This is all the code I wrote in test app.